# Unable to install R library of facebook prophet on CentOS7

Tags: r, docker, centos, facebook-prophet

I am trying to install `R` library for Facebook's `prophet` on centOS 7. For easy reproducibility, I am providing a `dockerfile` and commands.

```
FROM centos:7

RUN yum -y install epel-release
RUN yum -y groupinstall "Development Tools"
RUN yum -y install proj

RUN yum -y install udunits2-devel
RUN yum -y install openssl-devel
RUN yum -y install libjpeg-turbo-devel
RUN yum -y install libcurl-devel

RUN yum -y install v8-devel

RUN yum -y install R
```

To build the dockerfile, use following command.

```
docker build -t test_prophet_installation .
```

Once it is built, I run the container using this next command.

```
docker run -it --entrypoint=/bin/bash test_prophet_installation
```

Now, I am inside my container. I tried to install `prophet` using below command.

```
su - -c "R -e \"install.packages('prophet', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')\""
```

The above command said, one of the dependencies of `prophet` i.e `rstan` failed to install. So I tried to install 'rstan' using the following command.

```
su - -c "R -e \"install.packages('rstan', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')\""
```

After running the above command, I got the following error.

```
Error in .shlib_internal(args) :
  C++14 standard requested but CXX14 is not defined
* removing '/usr/lib64/R/library/rstan'

The downloaded source packages are in
        '/tmp/RtmpsPDQ9G/downloaded_packages'
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages("rstan", repos = "http://cran.rstudio.com/") :
  installation of package 'rstan' had non-zero exit status
2: In file.create(f.tg) :
  cannot create file '/usr/share/doc/R-3.6.0/html/packages.html', reason 'No such file or directory'
3: In make.packages.html(.Library) : cannot update HTML package index
```

I tried almost all the troubleshooting from Google to solve above error still no luck. I think, I am not setting some environment variable correctly.

Comment: It seems like the actual problem is that rstan is not installing. Is that right?  Did you check who owns that folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that when using the `yum groupinstall "Development Tools"`, the installed gcc is 4.8.5 and therefore does not support C++14 (as you can see [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx14)).

In order to solve this you need to add the following:

```
RUN yum -y install centos-release-scl
RUN yum -y install devtoolset-8-gcc*

RUN scl enable devtoolset-8 sh
```

on top of this, you have to define the Makevars for `rstan`. You can find an explanation here: https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan/issues/569

I created this Makevars:

```
CXX14 = g++ -std=c++1y -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-function -fPIC
```

and added a COPY in my Dockerfile:

```
COPY Makevars /root/.R/Makevars
```

I'm using the following command to download the packages:

```
install.packages('rstan', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/', dependencies = TRUE)
```

Some things are still not working as expected but it's a step forward.

EDIT:
this approach does not work since the system keeps using the old g++. I ended up using the docker image `centos/devtoolset-7-toolchain-centos7:latest`.